# É possível usar Elide com QLabel?

Tags: qt

Estou querendo usar o elemento [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel-members.html) e se o texto execeder o tamanho da largura ele pode ficar assim:

- Adicionar 3 pontos a direita:

  ```
  Foo bar baz foo bar...
  ```
- Adicionar 3 pontos a partir do centro:

  ```
  Foo bar ba...oo bar baz
  ```
- Adicionar 3 pontos a esquerda:

  ```
  ...bar baz foo bar baz
  ```

É possível fazer isto nativamente, ou tenho que reimplementar usando `QFontMetrics` com `QResizeEvent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do [Luiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172797/3635) me ajudou, todavia eu precisava de algo que fizesse automaticamente, pensei em usar o `paintEvent` ou algo assim, mas o `resizeEvent` funcionou bem,

- **elidedlabel.h**

  ```
  #ifndef ELIDEDLABEL_H
  #define ELIDEDLABEL_H

  #include <QLabel>

  class ElidedLabel : public QLabel
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      explicit ElidedLabel(QWidget *parent=0, Qt::WindowFlags f=0);
      explicit ElidedLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0, Qt::WindowFlags f=0);
      void setType(const Qt::TextElideMode type);

  public slots:
      void setText(const QString &text);
      void elide();

  protected:
      void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

  private:
      QString original;
      Qt::TextElideMode defaultType;
      bool eliding;

  };

  #endif // ELIDEDLABEL_H
  ```
- **elidedlabel.cpp**

  ```
  #include "elidedlabel.h"

  #include <QResizeEvent>
  #include <QTimer>

  ElidedLabel::ElidedLabel(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
      QLabel(parent, f)
  {
      defaultType = Qt::ElideMiddle;
      eliding = false;
      original = "";
  }

  ElidedLabel::ElidedLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
      QLabel(text, parent, f)
  {
      defaultType = Qt::ElideMiddle;

      //Usado para verificar se a string está ou não sendo atualizado
      eliding = false;

      //Guarda o texto original
      setText(text);
  }

  void ElidedLabel::setType(const Qt::TextElideMode type)
  {
      /*
         Altera o tipo de elide, podendo ser:
         Esquerda: "... bar baz"
         Meido: "Foo ... baz"
         Direita: "Foo bar ..."
      */
      defaultType = type;
      elide();
  }

  //Atualiza o texto se o Label for redimensionado
  void ElidedLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
  {
      Q_UNUSED(event);

      //O delay é necessário para evitar conflitos
      QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(elide()));
  }

  //Atualiza o texto
  void ElidedLabel::setText(const QString &text)
  {
      original = text;
      QLabel::setText(text);

      //Executa no momento que é atualizado
      elide();
  }

  void ElidedLabel::elide()
  {
      if (eliding == false) {
          eliding = true;

          QFontMetrics metrics(font());
          QLabel::setText(metrics.elidedText(original, defaultType, width()));

          eliding = false;
      }
  }
  ```

Para usar basta chamar assim:

```
#include "elidedlabel.h";

...

ElidedLabel label1;
```

Ou:

```
ElidedLabel *label1 = new ElidedLabel;
```

Answer (score 6):

Não parece haver nada nativo. Mas você pode utilizar o método [`QFontMetrics::elidedText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText) para implementar um "elided text" de uma linha. Eis um exemplo ([fonte original do exemplo no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382143/2896619)):

```
QString text("some long text without elipsis");
QFontMetrics metrics(label->font());
QString elidedText = metrics.elidedText(text, Qt::ElideRight, label->width());
label->setText(elidedText);
```

Há também [um exemplo mais completo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-elidedlabel-example.html) na documentação do Qt, em que uma nova classe específica pra isso é implementada para permitir fazer isso em Labels com múltiplas linhas. Ah, você também pode usar a classe `QxtLabel` [da extensão Qxt](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/index.html), pois ela já implementa o que você deseja no método [`QxtLabel::setElideMode`](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtlabel.html#elideMode-prop).